# How to make image sliders to come down and form a table?

Tags: javascript

I did a swiper slideshow that swipes images automatically and it is working very well. but now I would like to make all the images with the information written below it to go down after doing the slideshow and appear in the form of a table. Below is my source code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/swiper.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="swiper.min.css">
    <script type ="text/javascript" src="../js/swiper.min.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
        body 
{
      background: black;
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color:#000;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
}

.swiper-container 
{
      width: 100%;
      padding-top: 50px;
      padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.swiper-slide
{
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      background: white;
}

.swiper-slide .imgBx{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.swiper-slide .imgBx img{
    width: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide .details{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 20px;

}

.swiper-slide .imgBx h3{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.swiper-slide .imgBx h3 span{
    font-size: 16px;
    color: red;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body style="background: grey ;">
<div class="row" >
    <div class="col-md-3 input-group input-group-sm" style="margin-left: 70%; margin-top: 10px;">
        <input type="number" name="numb" class=" form-control col-sm" placeholder=" Mentors" >
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark  acc_active">Ment</button>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="row" style="margin-left: 350px; margin-top: 250px;" >
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="imgBx">
          <img src="book2.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="details">
          <h3>Image <span>SWE</span></h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"></div>

    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 container d-flex">
       <div class="box-1">
           <div class="ping">
           </div>
       </div>
        <div>
           <a href="table.php>"> <button id="btn-go"  style="width: 100px; margin-top: 0px;">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                Shuffle
            </button></a>
        </div>

                <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="imgBx">
            <img src="book2.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="details">
            <h3>Image <span>SWE</span></h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"></div>

    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   <div class="box-1">
       <div class="ping">
       </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



 <script type="text/javascript" src="swiper.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      effect: 'coverflow',
      grabCursor: true,
      centeredSlides: true,
      slidesPerView: 'auto',
      autoplay: {
        delay: 2500,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
      },
      coverflowEffect: {
        rotate: 60,
        stretch: 15,
        depth: 190,
        modifier: 3,
        slideShadows : true,
      },
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
      },
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
<?php
include "header.php";
?>
<?php
include "footer.php"
?>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. What did you try to solve this issue 
and what problem did you encounter?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Try to clarify "go down" a little more. And have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please try to get rid of everything we dont need to reproduce your example.